# Write xml utf-8 file with utf-8 data with ElementTree

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm trying to write an xml file with utf-8 encoded data using ElementTree like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                       
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                   

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import codecs

testtag = ET.Element('unicodetag')
testtag.text = u'Töreboda' #The o is really &#246; (o with two dots over). No idea why SO dont display this
expfile = codecs.open('testunicode.xml',"w","utf-8-sig")
ET.ElementTree(testtag).write(expfile,encoding="UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
expfile.close()
```

This blows up with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unicodetest.py", line 10, in <module>
    ET.ElementTree(testtag).write(expfile,encoding="UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 815, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 932, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Using the "us-ascii" encoding instead works fine, but don't preserve the unicode characters in the data. What is happening?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`codecs.open` expects Unicode strings to be written to the file object and it will handle encoding to UTF-8.  ElementTree's `write` encodes the Unicode strings to UTF-8 byte strings before sending them to the file object.  Since the file object wants Unicode strings, it is coercing the byte string back to Unicode using the default `ascii` codec and causing the `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Just do this:

```
#expfile = codecs.open('testunicode.xml',"w","utf-8-sig")
ET.ElementTree(testtag).write('testunicode.xml',encoding="UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
#expfile.close()
```

Comment: +1.  Just to clarify this: the problem is that you're trying to encode unicode->utf-8 twice: ElementTree does it once, and then the codec-enabled stream tries to do it again.  But this second pass gets confused since its input is already encoded (it expects a unicode string, but gets a utf-8 encoded byte string instead).

Comment: Here I go derping along thinking I'm helping by providing a unicode file... Can I just say that I LOVE stackoverflow? A perfect answer within 3 hours! Marks elaboration is explaining a lot too.

Comment: I've been dealing with utf-8 data and received a similar errors in ElementTree._serialize_text() or _serialize_xml() when attempting to write to an xml file. I was able to solve it by converting my strings to unicode using myString.decode('utf-8') before adding them to my ET.Element object. It seems ET.ElementTree.write() is not happy with other string encodings.