# Write xml utf-8 file with utf-8 data with ElementTree ... again

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

The title of this question is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046755/write-xml-utf-8-file-with-utf-8-data-with-elementtree), but my problem is different.

I have data read from a tar.gz archive using tarfile.TarFile.extractfile() and stored in an xml.etree.ElementTree.Element. The data is utf-8 encoded.

When I attempt to use xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write() to put it in a file, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../python/GetDoc.py", line 150, in <module>
    ET.ElementTree(elements).write(args.outfile, encoding="us-ascii", method="text")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 815, in write
    _serialize_text(write, self._root, encoding)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1007, in _serialize_text
    write(part.encode(encoding))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: How are you reading the data from the file?  Are you properly decoding it from UTF-8 to unicode objects?

Comment: That was quick! Indeed that seems to have been the problem. I had thought naively that ElementTree would be able to deal with UTF-8 strings. Go ahead and write an answer and I'll accept it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you reading the data from the file? Are you properly decoding it from UTF-8 to unicode objects?  ElementTree will want unicode objects, not bytestrings encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by converting my strings to unicode using myString.decode('utf-8') before adding them to my ElementTree.Element object. It seems ET.ElementTree.write() is not happy with other string encodings.